# Pdf text reflow in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am currently using `UIDocumentInteractionController` to view `pdf` files. I know I can use `UIWebView` also.

My question is,

Is it possible to do `text reflow` for pdf files in swift where I can change `font size` and make it easier to read ? Is there any `open source library` for that?

[I am saying something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVHp2.png)

Does apple PDFKit able to do it? Has any one tried it before?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very hard problem, there are some commercial PDF SDKs out there that offer this, but even then, it's often insufficient/not good.

Comment: hey bro, i tested out PDFKit for ios 11, and I can extract the text but sometimes, some text were left out like bullet point. Have u tried it out before?

Comment: is your PSPDFKit can do that text reflow properly?

Comment: @KyawHtetSoe Have you find something. I am also looking for similar thing.